# Was there a first known "force" user/s?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, history

As the Dai Bendu (pre Je'daii) were the first to use the force, was there ever a documented case of "a first person" to actually use the force before anyone else? or was the force something that people just came to use collectively?

Comment: Wouldn't be just a duplicate of [your former question?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/70572/32339)

Comment: @Deion Not quite. Before I wanted to know who the first "Jedi" were. Now I know that the Dai Bendu were before the Jedi and I was wondering if there was one person who may have acquired the force before anyone else.

Comment: Please define "first person". There are numerous references to beings using the force far before the Dai Bendu. Celestials being the first guess, "The Ones" being another.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero I don't know of these Celestial's or "The Ones" if there's any info on them, please post :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lore is unclear on who the first force users were. The Dai Bendu first started to develop an active connection to The Force by meditating on a massive pyramidal starship that they called [Tho Yor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tho_Yor). This occurred around 37,453 BBY.

In the year 36,453 BBY, the starship opened up and began communicating with the Dai Bendu using The Force. At the same time, seven other identical ships went active across the galaxy, gathered up Force-sensitive beings, and transported them to Tython.

This produces a bit of a snarl in the idea of a 'first Force user,' because the first known Force users that we have documentation of developed their powers by meditating on an ancient star ship that was obviously created by such advanced Force users that they had built a ship that could communicate with other races, regardless of species or language, through The Force. So, while the Dai Bendu are the first 'documented' Force users...they are pre-dated by other species.

One possibility for the 'first' actual Force users are the [Celestials](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial), whose Empire stretched back as far as 100,000 BBY, and are believed to have had such immense Force powers that Jedi and Sith legend suggest that they may have merged with The Force itself, and are actually the 'guiding' part of The Force. But we don't have anything concrete on that, just supposition.

REF: Star Wars Wiki, Darth Plagueis (novel), Star Wars: Dawn of the Jedi: Force Storm 1, and other assorted info stored in my brain.

Also, because you asked in the comments, here is info on [The Ones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ones)

Comment: Just the kind of answer I was looking for :) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the earliest instance of the Force being used consciously is the "Kwa" species. They were around over 100,000 years BBY and they were the ones who taught the Rakatan to use the Force. The Rakatan used the force to power their technology and create their Infinite empire.

Their usage isn't as passive as the Dai Bendu, but not as exclusive like the Jedi's and Sith's method of using the force.

The Celestials are an intriguing possibility, but no real records of them using the force is found. The Ones are said to be the descendents of the Celestials but there is no evidence that they are that powerful BECAUSE they are Celestials (or even If they're are indeed Celestials - their relation to the Celestials was recalled by the Kiliiks who were once the slave to the Celestials. But the Kiliiks can't tell the difference between facts and lores, being a hive collective )

The Ones are of a much closer timeline to Clone Wars.

So the directly recorded earliest usage of the Force should be the Kwa.

References:

On Kwa: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kwa
On the Celestials and the Kiliiks reminiscence of the Celestials: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Celestial/Legends

Comment: Hi there. Do you have sources for that, which you could [edit] in to improve your answer?

Comment: Hello Jenayah! Yup. Added the references.

Answer (score 0):

Iv been told that the sith-Ari was the first force user, ancient sith law tells of the perfect sith lord, and who became so powerful he couldn't die, his fate to me is unclear but his demise was told to have spread the midichlorians out into the universe, opening up the force to certain people the midichlorians saw fit, and their offspring became force-users as well. The sith await the return of a sith-Ari and many have killed their peers simply because they thought they were the sith-Ari. I'm not entirely sure if any of this is true, but it could be something to go on.

Comment: Do you have reference(s) for this information?